# Rotativa no me toma los estilos del html asp.net core (.net 6)

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rotativa

Estoy tratando de pasar una vista html a pdf con rotativa, ya se me crea el pdf, pero los estilos css no los toma el pdf y sale toda la información mal organizada, he hecho ya varias pruebas y no encuentro solución.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
     return new ViewAsPdf("Index")
        {             
           FileName = "Reporte.pdf"
       };
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la vista debería ser esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen al pasar a pdf no se respeta el diseño que se tiene con flexbox

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todos los elementos para reproducir el escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema pero usando grid, ¿pudiste encontrar la solución?. Tengo la sospecha que rotativa no tiene soporte para CSS3.